# COM context menu InvokeCommand not being called

Tags: c++, windows, com, windows-shell, com-server

I use the following code to set up my context menu:

```
HRESULT __stdcall CMyContextMenu::QueryContextMenu(HMENU hmenu, UINT indexMenu, UINT idCmdFirst, UINT idCmdLast, UINT uFlags) {
    if (CMF_DEFAULTONLY & uFlags)
    {
        return MAKE_HRESULT(SEVERITY_SUCCESS, 0, USHORT(0));
    }

    UINT idCmdCurrent = idCmdFirst;

    logging::log(conversions::to_string(idCmdCurrent));
    InsertMenu(
        hmenu,
        indexMenu,
        MF_STRING | MF_BYPOSITION,
        idCmdCurrent++,
        _T("Test Command")
    );

    logging::log(conversions::to_string(idCmdCurrent));
    logging::log(conversions::to_string(idCmdCurrent - idCmdFirst));
    return MAKE_HRESULT(SEVERITY_SUCCESS, 0, idCmdCurrent - idCmdFirst);
}

HRESULT __stdcall CMyContextMenu::InvokeCommand(CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO* pici) {
    logging::log("Test Command invoked");

    return S_OK;
}
```

I can see through logging, and through testing, that my command is being added to the context menus correctly.

However, when I click on the context menu item, my command is not being invoked. I went through the ID's for my command ad nauseam, but it seems to me that they are correct.

I am stumped for what my next step would be in debugging the extension. Please help?

Comment: If QueryContextMenu is called and the item shown, InvokeCommand should be called for as far as we can guess from this partial piece of code. Do you have a small reproducing project?

Comment: Do you handle the WM_COMMAND messages in whatever hosts the menu that you are adding to? The host should handle the WM_COMMAND by calling this IContextMenu::InvokeCommand function. If it is not invoked you might need to show part of the code that should be calling this from the hosting window

Comment: @SimonMourier I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I do have two context menu classes in the same DLL. I'm thinking that could be it? The other one works fine, but this one doesn't.

Comment: @SimonMourier I removed the other ContextMenu from my registry. Now this one works. It seems you can only have one implementation of IContextMenu in a project/dll. I must've missed something in the documentation.

Comment: No, you can have any number of a given COM interface implementations (here a coclass if you're extension the shell menus) in a given dll (and in a given machine). But you can have only one that corresponds to a given CLSID.

Comment: I made sure to have the correct CLSIDs. I'll see if I can draw up a minimal example tonight